# How to convert obtuse string to a javascript Date in Angular 12?

Tags: javascript, angular, date, string-formatting

While using Angular 12 I have a date as a string in a very custom format, from which I need to produce a Date object. An example of the date strings I have are:

```
20280328
20271201
```

To the human eye, these are obviously in the format `yyyyMMdd` however none of the standard parse functions appear to understand this (not unexpected.)

Other than simply breaking the string using substring, is there a better way to interpret these strings into a Date object?

I was hoping to be able to provide a custom input format for the `.parse()` function, but this does not appear to be available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/parsing-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: No, I've read that already and it is still automation attempting to identify the format from the input string. I need to specify the custom input format.

Comment: Did you read all of the answers?

Comment: If you're referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16235315/71376), no, I did not see that. Linking to that answer would have helped.

Comment: I cannot link directly to an answer using the SO "duplicate" tool

Comment: Consider `let [c, y, m, d] = '20280328'.match(/\d\d/g); let date = new Date(c+y, m-1, d)`.

Comment: @MattW—that answer will parse the string as UTC, use it if that's what you want. But it's an inherently inefficient strategy to parse a string to create a another string that is then also parsed to create a date. Just parse the string once and give the parts directly to the Date constructor.